# Unable to remove millis from joda dateTime object

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime, datetime-format

I tried different `ISODateTimeFormats` (`dateHourMinuteSecond()`, `dateTimeNoMillis()`) and my own format `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"`, to get time stamp be parsed to date time object without milliseconds, it failed.

For each format I tried to modify the string accordingly:

```
String value = "2011-01-24T09:45:00.000";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = ISODateTimeFormat.dateHourMinuteSecond();
value = value.substring(0, value.lastIndexOf('.'));
System.out.println("Formatted dateTime: "+formatter.parseDateTime(value));
```

Output:

```
Formatted dateTime: 2011-01-24T09:45:00.000Z
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did my tests in **jodatime 2.2**.

`formatter.parseDateTime(value)` returns a `DateTime` object. When you pass this object to `System.out.println`, it calls the `toString()` method of this `DateTime` object. And taking a look at the source code, I found out that it calls `ISODateTimeFormat`:

```
// (from jodatime source)
/**
 * Output the date time in ISO8601 format (yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSSZZ).
 * 
 * @return ISO8601 time formatted string.
 */
@ToString
public String toString() {
    return ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime().print(this);
}
```

To get the output you want (without milliseconds), you need to format the `DateTime` object:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
value = value.substring(0, value.lastIndexOf('.'));
DateTime datetime = formatter.parseDateTime(value);

// *** create the formatter with the "no-millis" format ***
DateTimeFormatter formatterNoMillis = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
System.out.println("Formatted dateTime: " + datetime.toString(formatterNoMillis));
```

The output will be:

```
Formatted dateTime: 2011-01-24T09:45:00
```

You could also do:

```
System.out.println("Formatted dateTime: " + formatterNoMillis.print(datetime));
//the output will be the same
```

Comment: thats helpful, but still I want the dateTime object without the millis, not as a string without, advice please!

Comment: The `DateTime` object **always** holds the millis value. Even if you parse a string without it, the milliseconds will be automatically set to zero. If you want to ignore just the millis part, you can implement your own subclass of `ReadablePartial` (you can take a look at `LocalDateTime`, which is a `DateTime` without timezone fields - you could do something similar to it, but also removing the millis field from it). I've never done a partial class, but that's how I'd start.